# Commlite Canon Lens adaptor putting black vignette on photo (EF-EOS R)

Tags: lens-adapter

I have Tamron 18-270 Lens F3.5-6.3 on a new Canon RP camera. I bought the Commmlite adaptor to use my old lenses.

I am getting a black ring around my photos (I can see this in the viewfinder)

I am new so please forgive the question if it is obvious.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems your lens is for APS-C format cameras, and your camera is full frame.

So, it's not the adapter itself, but the sensor size: Your lens projects an image big enough for APS-C sensors, but too small for the sensor of your camera.